# Get nid of a view in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I created a view that makes a block for my homepage. I need to render this block in my PHP. Problem is, I need the nid to render the node and I usually get these by going to Structure -> Blocks -> Click configure and the ID is in the page url at that point. For this view I created, there is no ID, just /admin/structure/block/manage/views/cfps-block/configure.

How can I get the ID so I can render this programmatically?

Comment: turns out it's a display ID not NID, and it's a text value not a number. It can be seen as "Machine Name" in the editing of the view.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly.

Open you view

For example:

> Blockquote

example.com/admin/structure/views/view/**custom_view**/edit

get the Machine Name of that view suppose it is **block**, than you can render it by using following code.

```
echo views_embed_view('custom_view', 'block');
```

Read the manual if any confusion:
 https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7